# Join multiple tables using single transformation using SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS, my task is to `join multiple tables` and insert it into a
destination table.

Source Tables are from SQL Server and Destination is again SQL Server.

All the tables have relationship and just need to join and insert the
data into SQL Server table again.

I want to do it with `SINGLE transformation` items in SSIS.

Please give me the steps to acheive this.

Comment: If tables are in one server you  can do this with Query...

Comment: a view can do ? this is fairly simple nothing to do with SSIS

Answer (score 5):

One way is to directly use an `oledb command` and write your sql by mapping the columns (`Column Mappings Tab`)

or

you can use a `merge join transformation` .Sort your OLEDB sources .Right click on the component Go to the `Show Advanced Editor`  and in the `Input Output Properties` select one of your output column and change `sort key option` from `0` to  `1`.Now use a merge join component and map the common columns as Join Key and select the columns which you need as output . Use an `OLEDB destination` to map the output columns from the above components and dump the data .

Check [this](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/101/posts/13416/ssis-97-when-merge-join-is-your-friend.aspx) article

Both the above 2 techniques uses only 1 component for performing joins

Comment: Hi, 
I dont want to do it using oledb command method. Using one Merge Join task we can join only two tables. i need to join multiple joins in single transformation.
 any ways to do this.
 thanks

Comment: First you join `2 tables` using `merge join` and the output from it should be combined from the 3rd OLEDB source and again do the same process for multiple `OLEDB source`

Comment: Hi, but only one time i can use the transformation to get the output. i mean only single trasformation (not more than 1 merge join ).

Comment: Then i think you don't have any other option than to use an OLEDB command and write a sql

Comment: is this possible to join multiple tables using single lookup using ssis 2008 ?

Comment: I am really sorry..I got wrong information..
 My actual question is, i  need to join multiple tables using some single trasformation/task. we can resolve this issue by  using merge join /oledb command and write sql statements.  
but my actual task is to find any other method is there instead that.i need to get it through some other method. That trasformation or task will not work with SSIS but my friends told me that we can do it through other methods that may be out of SSIS.but that trasformation/task should plug/work in ssis.
can anyone please  let me know how can I achieve this

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but the answers you have been given are the correct ones for your problem. If your friends know of another method, have them tell you what it is.  I can assure you that it is not a commonly used best practice, however.  You should also start marking the quality answers you have gotten to some of your questions so that others may share and learn from your problems.  You can accept an answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the best answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If the source tables are located in 1 single SQL server instance, you should use the 'OLEDB source' or 'SQL Server source'. 
In the data access method listbox, choose SQL command and write or build your join query.

The performance of this solution is much better then by using merge join transformations

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an OLE DB Source that only selects columns from your fact / transactional / most detailed table.

Then I would add a Lookup transformation for each reference table.

Finally I would add an OLE DB Destination to insert the data into the destination table (ideally with Fast Load and Table Lock).

This design provides the best runtime performance and ensures each component is simple and fast.